# Error when using GROUP BY with a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem in my SQL query: if I add `GROUP BY` the database engine always says "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

```
WITH install_count_join_date AS (
SELECT 
date_trunc('month', join_date) AS date, 
COUNT(*) AS "inscjoin"
FROM 
 apps202_prod.search 
WHERE 
 join_date >= '2016-06-01'
AND
  app_id = 3
GROUP BY 
  date_trunc('month', join_date)
  ), install_count AS (
SELECT
  DATE(original_timestamp) AS date,
  COUNT(*) AS "insc"
FROM 
  apps202_prod.search 
 WHERE 
  original_timestamp >= '2016-06-01'
AND
  app_id = 3
GROUP BY 
  DATE(original_timestamp)
) 

SELECT DISTINCT
  date_trunc('month', mr.date) AS "money_revenue_date",
  SUM(mr.amount) AS "amt",
  SUM(ic.insc) AS "install_count"
 FROM 
 mysql_apps202_prod.apps202_prod_money_revenue mr
  join install_count ic on date_trunc('month', ic.date) =         date_trunc('month', mr.date)
 WHERE
  date_trunc('month', mr.date)  >= '2016-06-01'
 AND
  mr.app_id = 3

 GROUP BY
   date_trunc('month', mr.date)
```

Hoping to resolve this thanks

Comment: please provide the error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause+or+be+used+in+an+aggregate+function

Comment: Which select causes the error ?..I know it's one request but can you try to see where is exactly the problem by executing them separatly ? Or does it happens once you group the 3 selects ?

Comment: Isn't the first part of WITH clause redundant?

Comment: I already removed the one that is being redundant but I still can't get the result that I wanted